# I am not able to configure reports in Jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit

I am configuring a Jenkins job to run PHPUnit after each GitHub commit

I selected Post build action ->  Publish Junit test result report

I selected 'Test Report XMLs' as **/results/phpunit.xml

I am getting following error message on applying this setting:

> ‘**/results/phpunit.xml’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not
>   ‘**/results/phpunit.xml’

I tried with `/results/phpunit.xml`, but still got the same, the results dir exists on my server at `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/results`
Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

[image: Please click this link to show the error image]

Comment: Are you sure that the test ran and it generated phpunit.xml files? can you use `**/results/phpunit.*xml` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Test Report XMLs setting without the slash:

```
results/phpunit.xml
```

instead of

```
/results/phpunit.xml
```

It might not be relative to your jenkins folder, but rather sees the first slash as the root directory.